# RSS feed from 2.1.4 no longer works with conditionals in 3.2.0

Tags: conditionals, rss

We just upgraded to 3.2.0 from 2.1.4, and the move seems to have broken my RSS feeds completely. I used several conditionals to assign the correct paths to each template group section, but none of those seem to work now. See the following for a representative example – perhaps you can divulge what I need to change for parsing to work in the new EE. (You’re seeing part of code that has worked for eight years until we updated.)

```
    {preload_replace:master_channel_name="restaurants|arts|community|kids|blogs|rural_road_trips|style|food|parties"}
{exp:rss:feed channel="{master_channel_name}"}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
    <channel>
   <title><![CDATA[Rural Intelligence]]></title>
    <link>{channel_url}</link>
    <atom:link href="{path=feed/RSS_2.0}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <description>Your guide to Rural Living</description>
    <dc:language>{channel_language}</dc:language>
    <dc:creator>{email}</dc:creator>
    <dc:rights>Copyright {gmt_date format="%Y"}</dc:rights>
    <dc:date>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
    <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://expressionengine.com/" />
{exp:channel:entries channel="{master_channel_name}" limit="19" rdf="off" dynamic_start="on" status="open" disable="member_data|trackbacks" category_group="1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|13|14|15"}
    <item>
{if channel_id=="24"}
      <title><![CDATA[{title} -- Restaurants -- {exp:channel:categories}{category_name}{/exp:channel:categories} ]]></title>
      <link>{title_permalink=food_section/food_restaurant_listing}</link>
      <guid>{title_permalink=food_section/food_restaurant_listing}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{article}]]></description>
      <dc:subject><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/exp:channel:categories}]]></dc:subject>
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
{/if}
{exp:channel:categories}
{if channel_id=="12" AND category_id=="16"}
{/exp:channel:categories}
      <title><![CDATA[{title} -- Arts Section -- {exp:channel:categories}{category_name}{/exp:channel:categories} ]]></title>
      <link>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_movies}</link>
      <guid>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_movies}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{article}]]></description>
      <dc:subject><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/exp:channel:categories}]]></dc:subject>
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
{/if}
{exp:channel:categories}
{if channel_id=="12" AND category_id=="17"}
{/exp:channel:categories}
      <title><![CDATA[{title} -- Arts Section -- {exp:channel:categories}{category_name}{/exp:channel:categories} ]]></title>
      <link>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_music}</link>
      <guid>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_music}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{article}]]></description>
      <dc:subject><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/exp:channel:categories}]]></dc:subject>
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
{/if}
{exp:channel:categories}
{if channel_id=="12" AND category_id=="18"}
{/exp:channel:categories}
      <title><![CDATA[{title} -- Arts Section -- {exp:channel:categories}{category_name}{/exp:channel:categories} ]]></title>
      <link>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_art}</link>
      <guid>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_art}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{article}]]></description>
      <dc:subject><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/exp:channel:categories}]]></dc:subject>
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
{/if}
{exp:channel:categories}
{if channel_id=="12" AND category_id=="19"}
{/exp:channel:categories}
      <title><![CDATA[{title} -- Arts Section -- {exp:channel:categories}{category_name}{/exp:channel:categories} ]]></title>
      <link>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_theater}</link>
      <guid>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_theater}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{article}]]></description>
      <dc:subject><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/exp:channel:categories}]]></dc:subject>
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
{/if}
{exp:channel:categories}
{if channel_id=="12" AND category_id=="20"}
{/exp:channel:categories}
      <title><![CDATA[{title} -- Arts Section -- {exp:channel:categories}{category_name}{/exp:channel:categories} ]]></title>
      <link>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_books}</link>
      <guid>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_books}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{article}]]></description>
      <dc:subject><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/exp:channel:categories}]]></dc:subject>
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
{/if}
    </item>
{/exp:channel:entries}
    </channel>
</rss>
{/exp:rss:feed}
```

You get the idea… What is going wrong in 3.2.0?

Thanks!

Terry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robin Sowell at EE found the problem, and of course it had to do with parsing -- but was in the last place I would have thought to look!

The long and short of it: We cannot nest `{categories}` tags any longer and get away with it. Never was a good idea - won't work at all now.

Here is a short example of what DOES work!

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="{master_channel_name}" limit="19" rdf="off" dynamic_start="on" status="open" disable="member_data|trackbacks" category_group="1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|13|14|15"}
    <item>

{categories}
{if channel_id=="12" AND category_id=="16"}

      <title><![CDATA[{title} -- Arts Section -- {category_name} ]]></title>
      <link>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_movies}</link>
      <guid>{title_permalink=arts_section/arts_articles_movies}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{article}]]></description>
      <dc:subject><![CDATA[{category_name}, ]]></dc:subject>
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
{/if}{/categories}
```

Now the conditionals work and parse-out just fine. I hope this helps someone else in a similar situation where you need to direct categories to specific template groups and templates.

Terry